# Application UUID changes with app update in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am storing path of downloaded file in sqlite db and when I update the app, its UUID changes but data doesn't get moved to new container. So the path is essentially invalid now. I checked if files still exist using iExplorer and they do.

```
platform.Is("iOS"){
this.localdirectory = this.file.dataDirectory+filename;
}
else
{
this.localdirectory = this.file.externalDataDirectory+filename;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A better approach to store UUIDs that need to be persistent between App installs would be to use the Keychain.

The keychain will not only persist between updates - but also between app installations. In fact - you can even remove the app altogether and it's still there.
Only completely setting up the device from scratch will actually give you a new value.

There is a gotcha (depending on how you build you Keychain domain) that different Provisioning profiles might get a new keychain (but old one still remains).

I do suggest using an open source to manage the keychain itself btw. It's really ... how should I put it ... different than a lot of modern code and conventions.
Also note - you can even use iCloud keychain in case you want to share across devices , and Appgroups to share among apps on the same phone.